# Write silence audio data into file ffmpeg C++

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, mu-law

I want to write silence/zeroed audio sampled data into `mov` media container file inside audio data. My audio data is G711 linear PCM-mulaw encoded data with one channel. Currently my code looks like:

```
AVFrame* pSilentData = av_frame_alloc();
memset(&pSilentData->data[0], 0, iDataSize);
pkt.data = (uint8_t*) pSilentData;
pkt.size = iDataSize;

// ...

av_freep(&pSilentData->data[0]);
av_frame_free(&pSilentData);
```

But this sounds noise like ***dot dot*** instead of silence. What's the problem?

Comment: Please post *actual code*, not an approximation, otherwise people may waste time addressing non-existent issues. Use copy and paste (i.e. don't re-type code) otherwise errors creep in.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. My actual code is okay and `unit8_t*`. Really sorry for your inconvenience. :(

Comment: OK - down-vote removed. Please be sure to post actual code in future (copy and paste is your friend).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [µ-law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm) audio the zero value is represented as `0xff`, so change:

```
memset(&pSilentData->data[0], 0, iDataSize);
```

to:

```
memset(&pSilentData->data[0], 0xff, iDataSize);
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem. I am grateful to you despite of the downvote :)

Comment: The down-vote was for posting inaccurate code, but since this has now been remedied I have removed the down-vote.